# dyplot.prophet scientific notation

Tags: r, dygraphs, forecast

Good afternoon everyone,

I use a dyplot to show my forecast for the upcoming period. The problem is that it's y-axis uses a scientific notation once values reach above 1.000.000. I know in standard dygraphs you have a dyOptions(maxnumberwidth) option but I don't know how to pass that to a dyplot.prophet function. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: don't know about `dyplot`, but doesn't `options(scipen = 999)` work?

Comment: Already tried to enter that in the console before running the code but it doesn't affect my plot in any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... Oops!

I must have done something wrong because it is completely possible to pass dyOptions to a dyplot.prophet function.

The solution is as follows:

```
dyplot.prophet(m.subset(), predict(m.subset(), fc.subset())) %>%
      dyOptions(maxNumberWidth = 20)
```